# Visual Studio # Serial Port ReadChar()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I'm doing simple COM port read application. Below is my DataReceive event code. The problem is: When I send more characters on COM port using Terminal, for example "TEST" it only reads first two characters, and the Counter increments only by 2. This happens all the time no metter how long the received data is.
Any ideas whats wrong?
Thank You!

```
        public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVariable.ReceivedCharacter =  serialPort1.ReadChar();
        GlobalVariable.Counter = GlobalVariable.Counter + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happend, because you read only one character for message. If you need read a text from serial port use `ReadExisting`. Simple example:

```
public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string recievedtext = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

If you need only a characters you can write something like this:

```
var mychararray = recievedtext.ToCharArray();
```